# ejs with node : variable in include

Tags: node.js, variables, ejs

Is it possible to put a variable in an include?

```
<%include <%= variable%>%>
```

Comment: This will not work. You cannot put `<%` or `%>` tags into another tags. If the variable can only have a few values use `if` or `switch` statement.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430012/ejs-pass-a-variable-to-the-included-file

Comment: in the example: include a source by passing a variable, 
I wanted to put the name of the source as a variable.